# Read/Manipulate data from an audio file and write it to a new audio file

Tags: python, audio, ffmpeg, pyaudio, pydub

For this question I'm looking less for specific code and more for pointers and recommendations. What I'm doing is custom enough that asking for code samples seems unfair.

I want to take the amplitude data from an audio track and use it to modulate the frequency of a tone. I'd like to record that modulated tone to a separate audio track.

At the moment I'm looking into pyaudio and pydub to run these tasks via a script.

I took this task for granted having used software that allows you to easily link track properties together. Or by manipulating data in real-time with an Arduino. Now that I'm looking into the scripting process I'm realizing how specialized what I'm trying to do is.

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: I’m not 100% sure SO is the right platform for this question. What I can recommend is how to split this problem. 1. Load a wav file and print the data, 2. Load a wave file and write it back out without processing. 3. Write a sine wave to a file 4. Write a sine wave with a lower gain to a file. 5. Join it all up by loading a file, multiply the data with a sine wave, write it to a file. Make sure you tackle 1 - 4 before 5 and you should be fine

Comment: Thank you, @fdcpp. That is helpful.